# php curl request get wrong value

Tags: php, curl

I am requesting to a url and get this url content using curl.but I found that some of result value not same as original url

mu curl code

```
$url="https://example.com/getDataV1P2.php?action=checkUpdates&lastmodified=2014-12-12%2014:08:09&userid=16";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

when I am requesting with original url using curl then

result show "SDL Blog Posts" : "1"

but when I am hitting from browser url to original url then result show "SDL Blog Posts" : "0"

I cant understand why

I am trying also this

```
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: See what is the difference between request headers in browser and your curl call, and fake them with curl...

Comment: yeah, what Glavic said, fake some headers especially User-Agent, Accept, and Language.

Comment: Give us the real url, so we can try it...

Comment: http://danoah.com/getDataV1P2.php?action=checkUpdates&lastmodified=2014-12-12 2014:08:09&userid=16

my original url @Glavić

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is not that you have wrong headers, but result is different based on your input.

If you call this url:

```php
http://danoah.com/getDataV1P2.php?action=checkUpdates&lastmodified=2014-12-12+12%3A00%3A00
```

response will be `"SDL Blog Posts" : "1"`, but if you increate hour by one:

```php
http://danoah.com/getDataV1P2.php?action=checkUpdates&lastmodified=2014-12-12+13%3A00%3A00
```

response will be `"SDL Blog Posts" : "0"`.

And please [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your values in url, because value `2014-12-12%2014:08:09` is incorrectly encoded, it should be `2014-12-12+14%3A08%3A09`.